# Filters in wxDataViewCtrl

Tags: wxwidgets

I have `wxDataViewCtrl` and I want to create filters like following:

[image]

One way I can modify `wxDataModel` and notify the control about the change.
Is there any other way to achieve the same without modifying `wxDataMdel`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you wouldn't really modify the data stored by the model but rather apply the filters on the fly in your custom model, i.e. take them into account in your overridden `GetValue()`. But you do need to do *something* at the model level to implement filtering, there is no way to do it at the UI/view level only.